# Create a partial view in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I try to create Data Driven Menu in MVC 3. So i complete following code :

Model :

```cpp
#region MenuTree
    public class MenuTree : BusinessObject
    {

        #region  Constructor
        public MenuTree()
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region Property
        #region ParentID
        private int _nParentID;
        public int ParentID
        {
            get { return _nParentID; }
            set { _nParentID = value; }
        }
        #endregion
        #region MenuName
        private string _sMenuName;
        public string MenuName
        {
            get { return _sMenuName; }
            set { _sMenuName = value; }
        }
        #endregion
        #region LinkText
        private string _sLinkText;
        public string LinkText
        {
            get { return _sLinkText; }
            set { _sLinkText = value; }
        }
        #endregion
        #region ActionName
        private string _sActionName;
        public string ActionName
        {
            get { return _sActionName; }
            set { _sActionName = value; }
        }
        #endregion
        #region ControllerName
        private string _sControllerName;
        public string ControllerName
        {
            get { return _sControllerName; }
            set { _sControllerName = value; }
        }
        #endregion
        #endregion

        #region Functions
        public MenuTree Get(int MenuTreeID)
        {
            return MenuTreeService.Instance.Get(new ID(MenuTreeID));
        }

        public ID Save()
        {
            return MenuTreeService.Instance.Save(this);
        }
        public void Delete()
        {
            MenuTreeService.Instance.Delete(ID);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Controller Part :

```
    public class TreeMenuController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /TreeMenu/

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View(MenuTrees.Gets());
            }

        }



view : 



@model ESimSolMVC05.Models.MenuTrees
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<table>
    <thead> 
    <tr>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> ParentID</th>
        <th> Menu Name</th>      
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    @foreach (ESimSolMVC05.Models.MenuTree item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ObjectID)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentID)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MenuName)</td>       
    </tr>

    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

then I try to call my view as a partial view in _layout with following code :

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/TreeMenu/index.cshtml")
```

But When i run my project I get an exception

My Exception Message is : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any one suggest me I can I call a partial view

Comment: Where is the Gets method defined? What's the MenuTrees class?

Comment: MenuTrees  is Collection class that contain a list of MenuTree that is me Model. note : If i user my view as a normal view than it is work successfully. But as partial view it not work!

Comment: What's the model of the main view from which you are calling this Html.Partial?

Comment: My view name is TreeMenu. That are located in Menutree folder but mt _layout located in Share folfer

Comment: also add @{ Layout=null; } in your partialview page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public PartialViewResult Index()
{
     return PartialView(MenuTrees.Gets());
}
```

use:

```
@Html.Partial("Index","TreeMenu")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Action to

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return PartialView(MenuTrees.Gets());
}
```

In _layout page

```
@Html.Action("Index","TreeMenu")
```